# Reload when user logs in

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I need to reload page when a facebook user logs in to my app

Say if i use

```
window.location.reload()
```

The page reloads indefinitely..
i need to reload the page only once after the user has logged in.

(Additional info:I am using Facebook Javascript SDK for authentication and PHP for MySql Queries)

Answer (score 1):

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  if( response.name){
window.location.reload();

}
});
```

It is just straight as documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: By a mean of Cookie you may able to prevent continuous reloading.